# Sort product collection by select attribute's option value sort_order - how?

Tags: sorting, join-table

I am trying to sort a product collection by an attribute that is of the 'select' type with lots of option values, all of which have sort order positions set. My attribute is called 'style'.

When I set my product collection to sort by the attribute I do get it sorted by that attribute, albeit alphabetically, not as per the position values.

```
    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToSort('style', 'asc')
        ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
        ->setCurPage(1)
    ;
```

This sorts the products alphabetically by style name (not style sort order values).

I have tried really hard to try to work out how to fix this.

As an added complication I am using 'flat tables' in the frontend.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `style_value` instead of `style`,**if flat table is enable**.

Comment: Thanks but the style_value is the option values, not the option sort order values, therefore it still sorts alphabetically.